# How can I force the calendar to display the timezone of the user whose calendar is being viewed, and not the timezone of the user doing the viewing?

Tags: calendar, timezone

Is there a way to have the calendar in Salesforce display event times in the timezone of the user whose calendar is being viewed/edited instead of in the timezone of the editing user/viewer? For instance, if I'm in EST zone and I'm logged in under my account and looking at a PST representative's calendar, the time is displayed in EST. Is there a way to make the calendar always display the time in the timezone of the calendar owner, and not the timezone of the user viewing that calendar? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is currently possible short of constantly changing your user timezone setting.

There are various applicable ideas:

- [Managing time zones when creating a new event/meeting](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpSH)
- [Option to set Event Time based on Location not User](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpwsAAC)